# Get Values of Pandas's Error messages / Exceptions

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have a bad csv data frame with a wrong line. Pandas raises an Error message with the line number. Is it possible to get this number to use it as except?

Here the error message:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 187 fields in line 55898, saw 188. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

I would like to get the line (55898) to write it in a separate log file and delete it afterward. It would be also nice to get the "expected" number (187) and the "saw" number (188) as well. So I could write in the log file :

```
Error at line 55898. Fields added : 1
```

Comment: What is the code that raises the error? You can wrap it around `try: except`

Answer (score 3):

Use `repr` to get the error string and `re` to munge the error.

```
import re

try:
   <code that raises exception>
except pandas.errors.ParserError as e:
   errorstring = repr(e)
   matchre = re.compile('Expected (\d+) fields in line (\d+), saw (\d+)')
   (expected, line, saw) = map(int, matchre.search(errorstring).groups())
   with open('error.log', "a+") as log:
      log.write(f'Error at line {line}. Fields added : {saw - expected}.')
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `pandas.errors.ParserError` is just a fancy `ValueError` ([see source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/errors/__init__.py#L33-L44)).

The rest is to wrap it into a `try-except` block and `str()` the exception:

```
import pandas as pd

try: 
    pd.read_csv('bad.csv')
except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
    msg = str(e)
    # Extract numbers and reformat the message for your needs.
```

There is no other way as Pandas generates the message and it is passed as `str` to `ParserError`.